# ¿Por qué cuando se renderea un HTML con angularJS me envia hasta el fondo de la misma al terminar de hacer el render?

Tags: angularjs, html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un proyecto web usando .Net Framework 4.5.2 en el cual para la parte del Front estoy usando AnguarJS sobre el html.

El problema al que me estoy enfrentando, y que no he encontrado solución, es que al hacer el llamado al *home* lo renderea sin problemas sin embargo al terminar de hacer el render la página se desplaza hasta el final.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. AngularJS y Angular son dos frameworks distintos deberías incluir solo la etiqueta del que se refiere tu pregunta, además de incluir algo de código  para poder ayudarte .

Comment: hola, el home es un .cshtml ?

Comment: Lo que veo raro es porque existe una etiqueta con angularjs 2.0, ya que no existe el concepto de js en angular 2, mas que nada porque en este se usa typescript, angularjs solo llega al 1.5.x

Comment: @LeandroTuttini El que creó la etiqueta estaba completamente equivocado; ahora mismo, esta sirve como alias para Angular 2. Pero para matener el orden esta etiqueta **debería ser eliminada**. Simplemente porque no existe una versión de AngularJS > 1.5.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón sobre eso, la comunidad está tratando de solucionarlo aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495/diferenciar-las-etiquetas-angular-y-angularjs

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si, es un .chtml